# Newline('\n') is replaced by space(' ') in ansible shell module

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

I have an ansible task where I make use of shell module to run a custom bash script. This bash script expects an optional parameter which could be a multiline string. Example

```
~/myScript.sh -e "Each \nword \nin \nnew \nline"
```

This works perfectly fine when I run it in the bash shell. However, I have tried several ways but haven't made it run via the ansible task. The value being a variable itself. The task below -

```
- name: Sample Task
  shell:
    cmd: "{{ home_dir }}/myScript.sh -e '{{ string_with_escaped_newlines }}'"
```

Here, the value of variable `string_with_escaped_newlines` is set to `Each \nword \nin \nnew \nline` programmatically by other tasks. The output of the task confirms this.
I had put an echo in my shell script to debug & I observe that the echo would print 2 different sequences in the 2 cases(running directly via shell & running via ansible).

Debug output via shell-

```
Each 
word 
in 
new 
line
```

Debug output via ansible -

```
Each  word  in  new  line
```

Notice that there is an extra space introduced in the value in place on `\n`. I do not understand why this happens and how do I stop this. I have checked/tried shell as well as command modules of ansible.

Comment: You are passing this variable to your script in simple quotes, but simple quotes are not interpreting new lines in shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cmd: "{{ home_dir }}/myScript.sh -e '{{ string_with_escaped_newlines }}'"
```

is first converted (by [Jinja2](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html)) to

```
cmd: "<THE HOME>/myScript.sh -e 'Each \nword \nin \nnew \nline'"
```

Here `\n` is within double quotes and in [YAML](https://yaml.org/) double quoted `\n`s are NEWLINEs (think `"\n"` in C or JSON).

For your case you can just write:

```
cmd: {{ home_dir }}/myScript.sh -e '{{ string_with_escaped_newlines }}'
```

Or to be more safe:

```
cmd: |
    {{ home_dir }}/myScript.sh -e '{{ string_with_escaped_newlines }}'
```

YAML syntax is quite "confusing". You can take a look at Ansible's own [YAML intro](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html).

Answer (score 1):

Given the script

```
shell> cat ~/myScript.sh
#!/usr/bin/sh
echo ${1}
```

```
shell> ~/myScript.sh "Each \nword \nin \nnew \nline"
Each 
word 
in 
new 
line
```

---

Q: ***"Newline '\n' is replaced by space ' ' in Ansible shell module."***

A: It depends on how you quote and escape the string. The simplest option is [single-quoted style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#732-single-quoted-style) because only `'` needs to be escaped

```yaml
string_with_escaped_newlines1: 'Each \nword \nin \nnew \nline'
```

You have to escape `\n` in [double-quoted style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#731-double-quoted-style)

```yaml
string_with_escaped_newlines2: "Each \\nword \\nin \\nnew \\nline"
```

Both variables expand to the same string

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: string_with_escaped_newlines1
    - debug:
        var: string_with_escaped_newlines2
```

gives

```yaml
string_with_escaped_newlines1: Each \nword \nin \nnew \nline
string_with_escaped_newlines2: Each \nword \nin \nnew \nline
```

Then, the quotation in the command is not significant. All options below give the same result

```yaml
    - command: ~/myScript.sh "{{ string_with_escaped_newlines1 }}"
    - command: ~/myScript.sh '{{ string_with_escaped_newlines1 }}'
    - command: ~/myScript.sh "{{ string_with_escaped_newlines2 }}"
    - command: ~/myScript.sh '{{ string_with_escaped_newlines2 }}'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    string_with_escaped_newlines1: 'Each \nword \nin \nnew \nline'
    string_with_escaped_newlines2: "Each \\nword \\nin \\nnew \\nline"

  tasks:

    - command: ~/myScript.sh "{{ string_with_escaped_newlines1 }}"
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout_lines

    - command: ~/myScript.sh '{{ string_with_escaped_newlines1 }}'
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout_lines

    - command: ~/myScript.sh "{{ string_with_escaped_newlines2 }}"
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout_lines

    - command: ~/myScript.sh '{{ string_with_escaped_newlines2 }}'
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout_lines
```

gives (abridged) four times the same result

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  out.stdout_lines:
  - 'Each '
  - 'word '
  - 'in '
  - 'new '
  - line
```

Notes:

- Using *shell* instead of *command* gives the same results.
- The best practice is using the module *command* [*unless the ansible.builtin.shell module is explicitly required*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#notes).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `\r\n` instead of `\n`

It helped me elsewhere in ansible

Comment: I'm trying to find the details, I only remember I was having similar issue in the past, but can't find the playbook :)